# Express Validate check Object has nested keys

Tags: node.js, json, validation, express-validator, nested-object

My express server handle a post request which receives a body containing the next JSON object:

```
"QnsAns": {

    }
```

How can I validate that object QnsAns HAS nested object? It should look like:

```
"QnsAns": {
        "Q1": "A1",
        "Q2": "A2",
        "Q3": "A3",
        "Q4": "A4",
        "Q5": "A5"
    }
```

Using express validator, I tried using '*' wildcard, optional(), exist() but all result with no success

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

To check if "QnsAns" constains "Q1" you can use **hasOwnProperty**

```
console.log(QnsAns.hasOwnProperty('Q1'));
```

To check type of Q1, you can use **typeOf**

```
console.log(typeof(Q1);
```

If you have to use this multiple times, try out [Joi Validations](https://github.com/hapijs/joi)

Answer (score 0):

The question is not very clear. Is this object in JSON format? Can you please post some more details to it so that it will help.

Now, as a simple solution you can do something like this, assuming the object is stored in a variable `data`.

```js
function checkIfNestedObjectIsEmpty() {

let data = <Your Object>

return (Object.entries(data[Object.keys(data)]).length === 0)
}
```